# Getting error when checking combobox for null value

Tags: java

I got a combobox, and a submit button, when the  button is submitted, i want to check if the combobox value was null. Im using this code:

```
ComboBox.setSelectedItem(null);
 if (ComboBox.getSelectedItem().equals(null)) {
           infoLabel.setText("Combo box value was null");
}
```

i am getting this error when i press the submit button:
***java.lang.NullPointerException***

how can i fix this?

Comment: Setting the selected value to null will make the selected value null as per the implementation. So, performing operations(calling 'equals') on (selected)null object will always yeild you NullPointerException try calling ``.getSelectedItem==null

Comment: if(ComboBox.getSelectedItem() != null && ComboBox.getSelectedItem().equals("checkedValue")). Also you may try to consider http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not call `equals` on `null`. Instead simply use `== null`.
Something like this:

```
ComboBox.setSelectedItem(null);
if (ComboBox.getSelectedItem() == null) {
    infoLabel.setText("Combo box value was null");
}
```

Should work.

Answer (score 2):

You can not give the `null` reference to `equals()`, do it like this:

```
ComboBox.setSelectedItem(null);
if (ComboBox.getSelectedItem() == null) {
  infoLabel.setText("Combo box value was null");
}
```

**And a remark that has nothing to do with your question:** I suggest using the [Java Naming Convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367), which would lead to your combo box being named `comboBox` (and not `ComboBox`).

Answer (score 1):

The condition should be :

```
ComboBox.getSelectedItem() != null
```

or

```
ComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("")
```

This checks if what is selected in the Combobox is null or empty

Another way of doing this is leaving the first item empty, then check for the selected index against 0 i.e

```
ComboBox.getSelectedIndex() != 0
```

Thanks